# Crontab execution fail to find my custom functions for Python

Tags: python, cron, environment-variables

I found that if type the following command in the Terminal for Python execution:

It works perfectly fine:

```
cd /Users/ws_fingear/Documents/workspace/zwoody_task/cmc   && /usr/local/bin/python3     cmc_stock_level.py
```

However, when I put the exact command in the crontab file, it says there is no module found.
I know that it should relate to the environment variable which I have already declared the PATH on the top of the crontab file (Like below):

> PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages:/Applications/Server.app/Contents/ServerRoot/usr/bin:/Applications/Server.app/Contents/ServerRoot/usr/sbin:/**Users/ws_fingear/Documents/workspace**

which my custom module is in **Users/ws_fingear/Documents/workspace** (and this path has been added into the .bash_profile)

May I know what is the issue to have such problem? Would that be the issue since I am just changing the User Crontab file so that I got such result?

Comment: What is the exact error you are seeing? Note that the PATH env var does not control the python module search path. You're probably setting PYTHONPATH in your interactive shell.

Comment: After I defined the PYTHONPATH & PATH in the top of the crontab file, found that the the WS_function can be able to import without any error.

However, found that my iOS shortcuts which are using the shell script to call Python script is not working right now.

My iOS shell script : cd/Users/xxxx/Documents/workspace/directory && /url/local/bin/python3 cmc_stock_level.py (ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'ws_functions')

But if I type the same command in terminal, it works fine. I am thinking of the shells are different when running in iOS shortcuts & Terminal I guess?